# How can I add value "auto" to a div?Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**CODE JS:**

```
$('.i_admin_user a').click(function(){

        var liHeight = $('.subMenu-1 > li').height() - 1;
        var subMenuHeight = 344;  //here I want auto value;

        $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('.subMenu-1').animate({height:0},300);
        $(this).siblings('.subMenu-1').animate({ height: subMenuHeight + 'px'},300)
           .addClass('active-submenu');

        if( $('.subMenu-1').hasClass('active-submenu')){
                $(this).siblings('.subMenu-1').removeClass('active-submenu');
        }else{

        }

    });
```

How can I modify my code so they accept and value "auto".

Basically I want instead of value `344` to put the value `auto`

I tried the next version but does not work (in this case the height of the return is 0)

```
var subMenuHeight = "auto";
```

Can you please tell me a solution to this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the correlation between your title and the actual question?

Comment: To give you a hint: You are writing `subMenuHeight + 'px'`, but if `subMenuHeight` is set to `auto` this would be simply wrong as there is no value `autopx`. The `px` has to be omitted in this case

Comment: Sorry title was my mistake ... I repaired

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the height to auto, you'll have to remove `px`.

Like so:

```
var subMenuHeight = 'auto';  // auto value here

$(this).siblings('.subMenu-1').animate({ height: subMenuHeight},300).addClass('active-submenu');
```

If you don't remove `px`, it won't regonize auto, because the value is then `autopx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(this).siblings('.subMenu-1').animate( height:auto},300).addClass('active-submenu');
```